# How to read and write xml tags using xsd?

Tags: xsd, xml-parsing

I am new to XSD programming.I want details description on this topic like how to create and read from XML using xsd?

**

What is real time Use of XSD?

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD isn't for creating or reading XML; it's for validating XML.

Use the XSD standard to declare the vocabulary and grammar for an XML document.  Then, a validating parser can report conformance with or violations against those constraints.

Comment: can you please provide me to detailed example of use xsd.

Comment: Please see [***XML Schema Part 0: Primer Second Edition***](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) for detailed examples and explanations.